# Missing .bpl files

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, c++builder, rad-studio, bpl

After compiling a FireMonkey project and executing the app on another PC I've encountered an error - "rtl190.bpl is missing".
So I searched google and I found the "solution" which didn't work for me.
It said that I should uncheck "Link with Dynamic RTL" and "Link with Delphi runtime...".
Indeed after compiling, the executable is bigger, but still I'm encountering the exact same error.
I must copy "rtl190.bpl" and "fmx190.bpl" manually to exe's directory in order to make it work.
How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should also uncheck `Build with runtime packages` under:

```
Project-> Options-> Packages-> Runtime Packages-> Link with runtime packages
```

Make sure to uncheck the three items ("Link with runtime packages", "Link with Dynamic RTL" and "Link with Delphi Runtime Library") under the build configuration you are using ('release' / 'debug').